# Can I create toString() of a specific method? Not the whole class

Tags: java, arrays, object, char, tostring

I have a class named `MyString{}`. I have created a method like this

```
MyString replaceAll(char oldChar, char newChar){

}
```

The method replace a char array by the oldChar and newChar. I have some other methods like upper one. But I want it, when this method is called it should return an object and that object will print the replaced array. I cant change my method type like

```
String replaceAll(char oldChar, char newChar){

}
```

Can I make toString method only for my methods? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, a method belongs to a *type*, not another method.

It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you just need to override `toString()` within `MyString`. Then when you call:

```
MyString x = new MyString(...);
String foo = x.replaceAll('x', 'y').toString();
```

that will call `toString()` on the `MyString` reference returned by `replaceAll`... which will presumably have all the appropriate `char` values replaced.

If that doesn't help, please clarify your question as it's pretty unclear at the moment.

Comment: When we write `MyString s = new MyString();` we can access the element of the my string class by `s.something` right? Now I want to create a kind of object by which we can have the access of a specific method's elements.

Comment: @TusharTushKhush: I'm afraid that's *far* too vague a description of what you're trying to do. *Methods* don't have "elements" - *objects* have state. You really need to clarify what you're trying to achieve.